# How can I put a QR-code in an alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to put a QR-code in an alert box. I am creating a QR code using zxing library so, the QR will first be generated as a bitmap. Here my problem is I can only set it as an icon but can't find a proper way to set as an image.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Drawable d;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            String text = et.getText().toString();
            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try {
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
                qr = bitMatrix.hashCode();
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                final Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                bit = bitmap;
                d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bit);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                builder.setTitle("hi");
                builder.setIcon(d);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("Code2care ", "Yes button Clicked!");
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.setView(iv).create().show();
                //builder.show();
            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

So I am getting a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
> on the child's parent first"

at `builder.setView(iv).create().show();`

When I use a solution found in web i.e. to add a image view to the dialog.

Any help will be useful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error log is pretty clear, the `iv` view was already added to another `ViewGroup`. To solve it, you should create a new `ImageView` instance instead of using `iv`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i have tried that to its not working. If you know any other way to do this please let me know. will be helpful

Comment: yes, app is crashing showing the same exception which i have mentioned in the question in the logs

Comment: Paste your edited code please. There's no way you got the same exception if you have changed your code to create a new `ImageView` instance instead of using the already existing one.